# misalignment of divs in table

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am badly stuck with the bootstrap css issue and i tried pull-left class to arrange div's but it did not work for me

And i dont want to use margin-left or bottom to my problem because that is disturbing the responsiveness of page

```
<div class="row">
                <!----><div ng-if="tableResource.displaySearch" class="manage-tools col-xs-12 col-md-3" ng-class="{'col-xs-12 col-md-3' : !tableResource.classSearch, '' : tableResource.classSearch}">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control search-instance ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" placeholder="Search ..." ng-model="$parent.$parent.search" ng-change="setPage(0)">
                    </div>
                </div><!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="!tableResource.hideFilters &amp;&amp; tableResource.filters !== undefined">
                    <!----><div ng-repeat="filter in tableResource.filters track by filter.filterId">
                        <div class="text-right manage-tools col-md-3 col-xs-4" ng-class="{'col-md-2' : !filter.customClass &amp;&amp; filter.filterType !== 'dropdown', 'col-md-3 col-xs-4' : !filter.customClass &amp;&amp; filter.filterType === 'dropdown', 'hidden-sm hidden-xs' : !filter.customClass &amp;&amp; filter.filterType !== 'switch' &amp;&amp; filter.filterType !== 'dropdown', 'col-xs-4' : !filter.customClass &amp;&amp; filter.filterType === 'switch', '': filter.customClass}" style="">
                           <!----><label ng-if="filter.filterText" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: unset;"> </label><!---->
                           <!---->
                        </div>
                        <!---->
                        <!----><div ng-if="filter.filterType === 'dropdown'" class="manage-tools col-md-5 col-xs-8" ng-class="{'col-md-5 col-xs-8': !filter.customClass &amp;&amp; !tableResource.actions, 'col-md-2 col-xs-4': !filter.customClass &amp;&amp; tableResource.actions, '': filter.customClass}">
                           <div class="dropdown" style="">
                              <!----><i ng-if="filter.showFilterIcon" class="fa fa-filter fa-fw"></i><!----> 
                              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">ALL&nbsp;
                              <span class="caret"></span></button>
                              <!----><div class="dropdown-menu" ng-if="filter.filterOptions.length">
                                <!----><div ng-repeat="filterOption in filter.filterOptions" class="operator-item" ng-click="filterBy(filter.filterId,filterOption)">
                                    <span>ALL</span>
                                    <br>
                                </div><!----><div ng-repeat="filterOption in filter.filterOptions" class="operator-item" ng-click="filterBy(filter.filterId,filterOption)">
                                    <span>TIMESTAMP</span>
                                    <br>
                                </div><!----><div ng-repeat="filterOption in filter.filterOptions" class="operator-item" ng-click="filterBy(filter.filterId,filterOption)">
                                    <span>VARCHAR</span>
                                    <br>
                                </div><!----><div ng-repeat="filterOption in filter.filterOptions" class="operator-item" ng-click="filterBy(filter.filterId,filterOption)">
                                    <span>BIGINT</span>
                                    <br>
                                </div><!----><div ng-repeat="filterOption in filter.filterOptions" class="operator-item" ng-click="filterBy(filter.filterId,filterOption)">
                                    <span>NUMERIC</span>
                                    <br>
                                </div><!----><div ng-repeat="filterOption in filter.filterOptions" class="operator-item" ng-click="filterBy(filter.filterId,filterOption)">
                                    <span>CHAR</span>
                                    <br>
                                </div><!----><div ng-repeat="filterOption in filter.filterOptions" class="operator-item" ng-click="filterBy(filter.filterId,filterOption)">
                                    <span>BOOLEAN</span>
                                    <br>
                                </div><!---->
                              </div><!---->
                            </div>
                        </div><!---->
                        <!---->
                    </div><!---->
                </div><!---->

                <div ng-hide="tableResource.hideAction">
                    <!---->
                    <!---->
                </div>
```

filter div should be inline with search box as lhs table and for the lhs table i took col-xs-6 and map button is col-xs-1 and rhs table is col-xs-5[image]

Comment: Unsolicited protip: Don't use breaks for formatting. Use a CSS class (or use a div).

Comment: It would be easier to troubleshoot this if you showed us rendered markup instead of your Angular stuff.